# Webcam driver missing

Tags: windows-10, drivers, 64-bit, webcam, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite P55W-C5200X laptop. I had to do a clean install of Windows 10 Home x64. But now I don't have the webcam being recognized in Device Manager. How do I install a driver/get it working? I went to Toshiba's site and there is no way to get the driver. Under Device Manager there is no Imaging section.

No Image section below in device manager
[image]

Comment: I had no trouble finding the drivers for your device [P55W-C5200X](https://support.dynabook.com/support/driversOSResults?freeText=1200010651).  I hate to submit a comment like this but given that I was able to find the correct page within seconds, performing a search on "P55W-C5200X drivers", I must give you the chance, to install the correct drivers.  Any answer I submit would be a link to the driver page for your device.  Given the lack of research, this likely would result in downvotes for everyone.  I will answer, but I require a screenshot, of the unidentified devices in Device Manager.

Comment: I could find the drivers page. But the problem is I don't see a download for webcam/camera. It is not there unless named something else.

Comment: I would assume `Toshiba Face Recognition` would install the required software.  You have attempted to run Windows Update?

Comment: The `Toshiba Face Recognition` doesn't do anything. I extract it then it just closes after asking for admin access. Maybe it doesn't apply. But that didn't work. I installed proset and the chipset. Going to reboot see if it works. May just have to buy external webcam.

Comment: Please provide the required information necessary to answer your question.  There must be an identified device that is being discovered, I need more information, to indicate the solution to your problem.  Please do not submit a comment in response to this request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webcam was disabled in the BIOS. Enabling the webcam fixes the problem.